# Delay haproxy 5 seconds in supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I saw this on another thread which solved delaying a process start in supervisord (delayed 5 seconds):

```
command=bash -c 'sleep 5 && uwsgi /etc/uwsgi.ini'
```

How would one do this to do the following:

```
command=service haproxy start
```

Comment: One solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58954517/209139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command=bash -c 'sleep 5 && /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy.conf'
```

Change the binary location and config file above to suite your system. if you need additional settings - add to the end of the line before the '

Answer (score 2):

The example commands above may stop supervisord from being able to detect the state of the program, or sending it signals, since it'll send the signal to bash and not your program. This *might* be okay, but also might not be, depending on how your program behaves WRT process groups.

Instead, use `command=bash -c 'sleep 5 && exec uwsgi /etc/uwsgi.ini'`.